# ASP.NET Membership Works Locally but not deployed to Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure

I implemented ASP .NET membership over SQL Azure , everything works fine in my local machine, however when I deploy to Azure, the login just fail mysteriously.

I tried the solution here, [ASP.NET Membership - login works locally, fails on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415822/asp-net-membership-login-works-locally-fails-on-azure) and the blog

http://geekswithblogs.net/DavidHoerster/archive/2010/06/15/asp.net-membership-password-hash----.net-3.5-to-.net-4.aspx

but still has no luck? Anyone has similar experience?

Andy.

Comment: Fail means what? You see an exception? Get redirected to login? Have you used Fiddler to gather more details? Did you apply   <system.web?<customErrors mode="Off" />? Have you set  <system.webServer><httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />?

Comment: same username and password, used Fiddler, check and 100% sure it tallies. Not exception thrown but just says Login failed (i.e. standard login failed message thrown)

Comment: You said you tried the solution. I'm just curious - did you put validationKey and decryptionKey in web.config? Does login fail for both old users and new users, or just old users?